# setTimeout doesn't work with addon

Tags: firefox-addon, settimeout, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making an addon with builder.addons.mozilla, I've posted the main.js code below. The idea is, when I click the widget of the addon, it disables a script running at panelist-webiq-cdn.appspot.com/warptest by setting the disableWebIQ variable to true. Setting the variable works, but whenever the addon is installed, the setTimeout call in the script in the page doesn't work. Does adding a PageMod to a page disable setTimeout?

The code of the button script and myScript.js doesn't do much, and myScript.js doesn't run when you click the widget anyways, so I doubt it's what's disabling setTimeout in the page.

```js
var ss = require("simple-storage");
ss.storage.enabled = true;
ss.storage.panelIdList = [];
const widgets = require("widget");
const data = require("self").data;

var player = widgets.Widget({
    id: "player",
    width: 16,
    label: "PanelistWebIQ",
    contentURL: data.url("buttons.html"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("buttonScript.js"),
    onClick: function(){
        if(ss.storage.enabled){
            ss.storage.enabled = false;
            pageMod.destroy();
        }
        else{
            ss.storage.enabled = true;
            pageMod = pageModModule.PageMod({
                include: "*",
                contentScriptWhen: 'start',
                contentScriptFile: data.url('myScript.js')
            });
        }
    }
});

var pageModModule = require("page-mod");
var pageMod = pageModModule.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'start',
    contentScriptFile: data.url('myScript.js'),
    onAttach: function(worker){
        var url = worker.url;
        var newPanelId = '';

        if(url.match(/^https?:\/\/panelist-webiq-cdn.appspot.com.*panelId=.*$/)){
            var pattern = 'panelId=';
            var index = url.indexOf(pattern);
            var sub = url.substring(index + pattern.length);
            index = sub.indexOf('&');
            if(index==-1){
                newPanelId = sub;
            }
            else{
                newPanelId = sub.substring(0, index);
            }
        }

        var list = ss.storage.panelIdList;
        if(newPanelId){
            var matchFound = false;
            for(var ctr=0; ctr<list.length; ctr++){
                var panelId = list[ctr];
                if(panelId==newPanelId){
                    matchFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!matchFound){
                list.push(newPanelId);
            }
        }
        worker.postMessage(list + '');
    }
});
```

Comment: No, content scripts definitely don't usually disable timeouts. But it should be easy enough for you to test whether `myScript.js` is relevant - replace it by an empty file and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you have an alert in your script, that alert can disable future calls to setTimeout. I removed all alerts from my addon, and it worked fine.